# Vehicle Routing Prob with non-connected graph or-tools Python

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm using this python library or-tools: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing 
(the code can be found here).

The problem is that when you run the solution it gives you a path to take that covers all of the nodes once. But my project needs constraints on the paths between nodes. For example, if you are on node {3} you may not travel to node {18}. Or in another way, if you are at node {5} you can only travel to nodes {1, 12, 14}. I'm unsure how to add this constraint into the current code example.

Allow me to explain further...

If we were to look at this graph:
[image]

You may see a representation of this graph here: 
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/networkx-python-graph-tutorial

Clearly in this problem you can not travel to certain nodes from other nodes. I am using the data from this graph in the google or-tools example to obtain a vehicle routing problem solution.

Here is my code:

```
import math
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)**(1/2)

    return dist
class CreateDistanceCallback(object):
  """Create callback to calculate distances between points."""

  def __init__(self, locations):
    """Initialize distance array."""
    size = len(locations)
    self.matrix = {}

    for from_node in range(size):
      self.matrix[from_node] = {}
      for to_node in range(size):
        x1 = locations[from_node][0]
        y1 = locations[from_node][1]
        x2 = locations[to_node][0]
        y2 = locations[to_node][1]
        self.matrix[from_node][to_node] = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)

  def Distance(self, from_node, to_node):
    return int(self.matrix[from_node][to_node])

# Demand callback
class CreateDemandCallback(object):
  """Create callback to get demands at each location."""

  def __init__(self, demands):
    self.matrix = demands

  def Demand(self, from_node, to_node):
    return self.matrix[from_node]

def main():
  # Create the data.
  data = create_data_array()
  locations = data[0]
  demands = data[1]
  num_locations = len(locations)
  depot = 0    # The depot is the start and end point of each route.
  num_vehicles = 1

  # Create routing model.
  if num_locations > 0:
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(num_locations, num_vehicles, depot)
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()

    # Callback to the distance function.
    dist_between_locations = CreateDistanceCallback(locations)
    dist_callback = dist_between_locations.Distance
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(dist_callback)

    # Put a callback to the demands.
    demands_at_locations = CreateDemandCallback(demands)
    demands_callback = demands_at_locations.Demand

    # Add a dimension for demand.
    slack_max = 0
    vehicle_capacity = 1500
    fix_start_cumul_to_zero = True
    demand = "Demand"
    routing.AddDimension(demands_callback, slack_max, vehicle_capacity,
                         fix_start_cumul_to_zero, demand)

    # Solve, displays a solution if any.
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if assignment:
      # Display solution.
      # Solution cost.
      print("Total distance of all routes: " + str(assignment.ObjectiveValue()) + "\n")

      for vehicle_nbr in range(num_vehicles):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_nbr)
        index_next = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        route = ''
        route_dist = 0
        route_demand = 0

        while not routing.IsEnd(index_next):
          node_index = routing.IndexToNode(index)
          node_index_next = routing.IndexToNode(index_next)
          route += str(node_index) + " -> "
          # Add the distance to the next node.
          route_dist += dist_callback(node_index, node_index_next)
          # Add demand.
          route_demand += demands[node_index_next]
          index = index_next
          index_next = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))

        node_index = routing.IndexToNode(index)
        node_index_next = routing.IndexToNode(index_next)
        route += str(node_index) + " -> " + str(node_index_next)
        route_dist += dist_callback(node_index, node_index_next)
        print("Route for vehicle " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ":\n\n" + route + "\n")
        print("Distance of route " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ": " + str(route_dist))
        print("Demand met by vehicle " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ": " + str(route_demand) + "\n")
    else:
      print('No solution found.')
  else:
    print('Specify an instance greater than 0.')

def create_data_array():

  nodelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv')

  locations = [[e.X, e.Y] for e in nodelist.itertuples()]
  demands = [1] + [1] + [1] * 75

  data = [locations, demands]
  return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This outputs a solution:

```
Total distance of all routes: 12900

Route for vehicle 0:

0 -> 56 -> 40 -> 53 -> 63 -> 55 -> 14 -> 15 -> 12 -> 26 -> 34 -> 69 -> 36 -> 1 -> 64 -> 27 -> 48 -> 70 -> 47 -> 13 -> 10 -> 61 -> 45 -> 42 -> 60 -> 9 -> 8 -> 21 -> 43 -> 44 -> 3 -> 18 -> 58 -> 38 -> 28 -> 49 -> 32 -> 35 -> 50 -> 74 -> 46 -> 54 -> 76 -> 71 -> 65 -> 29 -> 16 -> 17 -> 22 -> 59 -> 7 -> 24 -> 31 -> 37 -> 67 -> 73 -> 41 -> 52 -> 75 -> 72 -> 20 -> 2 -> 39 -> 57 -> 23 -> 66 -> 5 -> 6 -> 30 -> 33 -> 68 -> 19 -> 25 -> 4 -> 11 -> 62 -> 51 -> 0

Distance of route 0: 12900
Demand met by vehicle 0: 76
```

So as you can see we are traveling between nodes that cannot be travelled between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Capacitized Vehicular Routing Problem relies on a complete graph, which you don't have here. No problem - we can replace the original graph with a complete one in which the distance between any two nodes the shortest distance between them on the original graph. That is easily (`O(n^3))` - not so easily) computed by Floyd-Warshall, which I'll do in `networkx` as I'm more familiar with it. Replace by an `ortools` version if available. Sot the `CreateDistanceCallback` now looks like

```
class CreateDistanceCallback(object):
  '''Create callback to calculate distances between points.'''

  def __init__(self, G):
      '''Calculate shortest paths using Floyd-Warshall'''
      self.paths = nx.floyd_warshall(G)

  def Distance(self, from_node, to_node):
      return self.paths[from_node][to_node]
```

It takes a `nx.Graph()` object, so replace `create_data_graph()` by

```
def create_data_graph():
    edgelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/e570c38bcc72a8d102422f2af836513b/raw/89c76b2563dbc0e88384719a35cba0dfc04cd522/edgelist_sleeping_giant.csv')
    nodelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv')

    node_dict = dict(zip(nodelist['id'], list(range(nodelist.shape[0]))))

    G = nx.Graph()

    for i, elrow in edgelist.iterrows():
        G.add_edge(node_dict[elrow.node1], node_dict[elrow.node2], weight=elrow.distance)

    locations = [[e.X, e.Y] for e in nodelist.itertuples()]
    demands = [1] + [1] + [1] * 75

    return G, locations, demands
```

The first lines in `main()` are now adjusted for the new input data

```
  # Create the data.
  G, locations, demands = create_data_graph()
```

and replace the instantiation of the `CreateDistanceCallback` object by

```
    dist_between_locations = CreateDistanceCallback(G)
```

When I run, I get the output:

```
Total distance of all routes: 2

Route for vehicle 0:

0 -> 68 -> 75 -> 73 -> 76 -> 74 -> 71 -> 1 -> 8 -> 3 -> 9 -> 10 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 16 -> 15 -> 18 -> 21 -> 17 -> 22 -> 19 -> 20 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 11 -> 72 -> 67 -> 69 -> 70 -> 65 -> 64 -> 63 -> 61 -> 60 -> 58 -> 50 -> 55 -> 59 -> 62 -> 66 -> 52 -> 39 -> 37 -> 56 -> 51 -> 57 -> 25 -> 33 -> 41 -> 31 -> 36 -> 54 -> 49 -> 48 -> 53 -> 47 -> 46 -> 45 -> 44 -> 43 -> 42 -> 35 -> 38 -> 34 -> 32 -> 29 -> 28 -> 27 -> 26 -> 24 -> 40 -> 7 -> 30 -> 23 -> 0

Distance of route 0: 49.440000000000005
Demand met by vehicle 0: 76
```

Could you check this?

To print the "extended path" as requested, rewrite the last section of `main()`:

```
    ext_route = ''
    last_node = None
    while not routing.IsEnd(index_next):
      node_index = routing.IndexToNode(index)
      node_index_next = routing.IndexToNode(index_next)
      route += str(node_index) + " -> "
      if last_node is not None:
          last_path = nx.dijkstra_path(G,last_node, node_index)
          ext_route += repr(last_path) + " -> "
      # Add the distance to the next node.
      route_dist += dist_callback(node_index, node_index_next)
      # Add demand.
      route_demand += demands[node_index_next]
      index = index_next
      index_next = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
      last_node = node_index

    node_index = routing.IndexToNode(index)
    node_index_next = routing.IndexToNode(index_next)
    route += str(node_index) + " -> " + str(node_index_next)
    route_dist += dist_callback(node_index, node_index_next)
    print("Route for vehicle " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ":\n\n" + route + "\n")
    print("Expanded route for vehicle " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ":\n\n" + ext_route + "\n")
    print("Distance of route " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ": " + str(route_dist))
    print("Demand met by vehicle " + str(vehicle_nbr) + ": " + str(route_demand) + "\n")
```

Comment: I see. So the shortest path between two nodes is the distance. That's actually a nice solution. ~~I'm still getting an error here though~~ Never mind, I figured it out. One last thing, is there anyway to preserve the solution of shortest path between the two nodes so if I want to visualize the actual path I can go back and see each node it passed through to get there.

Comment: I hope that comment makes sense. So I guess what I'm saying is if to go from `3 -> 22` the shortest path was actually to go `3 -> 5 -> 14 -> 16 -> 22` then somehow pull out that shortest path and place it into the final solution.

Comment: I added the additional logic in my answer. It wouldn't be too hard to generate a graphical solution in graphviz or networkx.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose an alternative solution to Charles Pehlivanian. To forbid transitions between certain pairs of nodes you could try to make them too expensive for them to appear in an assignment. First compute a upper bound on the most expensive route that visits all stops. For example the greatest distance among all edges time the number of stops:

```
penalty = len(locations) * max(distance(x,y) for x,y in edges)
```

Then set the value of forbidden transitions in the matrix to that value:

```
if forbidden(from_node, to_node):
    self.matrix[from_node][to_node] = penalty
else:
    self.matrix[from_node][to_node] = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

(At first sight) this looks like some wrapper for some already implemented specialized solver. Maybe changing internals is not as easy.

But an easy workaround: just change the `distance-callback` so that it gives very high costs for your forbidden edges.

This approach needs tuning and is not perfect. But it's a workaround.

If this makes sense, depends on your task, which looks pretty informally described.

Comment: I added some more detail to my question with an example. I think you're solution should work, however, I'm not sure if the google or-tools has somewhere in it that the solution *must not* go back to a previous node. In this case it will still take the high cost because it can't take the closest node.